# Ajax Based Select2 Codeigniter Issue

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, jquery-select2

Hi friends I am trying to do a Ajax Based select2 using codeigntier. I am using 4.0.1 Select2 Version. I am getting the response from ajax but the result is not showing in SELECT2. Can you please check the code below and tell me where I have done wrong.

**Here is my Model**

```
//Model
class AddServiceAreaModel extends CI_Model
{
    //Function for getting suburbs from restaurant
    //MAIN FUNCTION FOR DATATABLE
    public function get_postcodes($q)
    {
        $query = $this->db->select('postcode')
                          ->group_by('postcode')
                          ->like('postcode', $q)
                          ->get('tbl_suburb');

        $json = $query->result_array();
        echo json_encode($json);
    }
}
```

**Here is my View**

```
<div id="page-inner">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12"> 
      <!-- Advanced Tables -->
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading"> Add Service Area</div>
        <form id="addFrm">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div class=""> 

              <!-- Modal content-->
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="postcode">Postcode</label>
                    <select class="selectbox form-control required" id="postcode" name="postcode"></select>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <!--End Advanced Tables --> 
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /. ROW  --> 
</div>
<script type="text/javascript"> 

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#postcode').select2({
            placeholder: 'Select for tag',
            ajax: {
              url: '<?php echo base_url('restaurant/addservicearea/get_postcode') ?>',
              dataType: 'json',
              delay: 250,
              processResults: function (data) {
                return {
                  results: data
                };
              },
              cache: true
            }
      });
   });
</script>
```

**Here is My Controller**

```
public function get_postcode()
    {
        //$_GET['term']. Term is the variable is in jquery-ui.js file.
        if(isset($_GET['term']))
        {
          $q = $_GET['term'];
          $this->AddServiceAreaModel->get_postcodes($q);
        }
    }
```

**The output showing blank result even i got the response in ajax.**

[image]

Can you please help me where i am wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Earlier I thought you need a success function, but select2 uses the processResults function. It turns out, you just need that to look like this:

```
processResults: function (data) {
    return {
      results: data.items
    };
},
```

Then, in PHP when you send back your response, select2 expects an items element, and then arrays that contain "id" and "text":

```
// This is just a sample, of course yours will be dynamic
echo json_encode(array(
    'items' => array(
        array('id' => '0', 'text' => '12345'),
        array('id' => '1', 'text' => '12346'),
        array('id' => '2', 'text' => '12347')
    )
);
```

I tested this out locally, and I was getting results after making these changes. Should work for you now.

Comment: Not working at all. Please check and let ,me know. thank you

Comment: I got it working now and revised my answer. I tested this locally with CI3.